# How to read from buffer every second?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing script that will reload my app, once I changed a code.

So far I have the part that will provide the name of the service the changes come from:

```
inotifywait $ENVPATH --recursive --monitor --event CREATE --event MODIFY  --event DELETE | grep --line-buffered -Eiv ".idea|.phpstorm.meta.php|runtime|.swp|.log"
```

But when I write code, I don't want to have multiple firing reloading events a second, so I need to buffer this stream. I would like to read all the data available till the moment every x second.

How to to it with bash, so far I know only this way to read data, but it don't suit my needs

```
while read line
do
  echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: I think you have to deal with `inotifywait` in a more constructed way... waiting only for relevant events and confine in some variable (array?) what to do before doing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can actively ignore everything that `inotifywait` outputs for specified amount of time.

```
inotifywait ... |
while read line
do
     echo "$line"
     # ignore input for 1 second
     timeout 1 cat >/dev/null
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`read -t 0` will check if there is input available without actually reading it. You can use it to check if there are any buffered up events that should be ignored.

```
inotifywait -rm -e CREATE -e MODIFY -e DELETE "$ENVPATH" \
    --exclude '\.idea$|\.phpstorm.meta.php$|runtime|\.swp$|\.log$' |
    # Block until there's an event.
    while read -r dir event path; do
        # Discard all remaining events.
        while read -t 0; do read -r dir event path; done
    done
```

Note that you can use `--exclude` to filter out files directly from inotifywait.